# How can I keep the cursor position when piping the buffer through an external command?

Tags: external-command, line-numbers, cursor

I sometimes make shortcuts for myself, which run some external command on the current buffer, such as

```
nnoremap <C-f> :%!clang-format -style=file<C-m>
```

which formats the buffer with clang's formatter.

However, this makes the cursor jump to the beginning of the file. Is there some way to avoid this?
I understand it would be difficult finding the correct line after reformatting, but just the same line number would be good. I assume one could set and use marks in the mapping somehow, but any smarter solution would also be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See `:h getcurpos()`

Basically there is an example:

```
        This can be used to save and restore the cursor position: >
            let save_cursor = getcurpos()
            MoveTheCursorAround
            call setpos('.', save_cursor)
```

So you can try it with smth like (untested):

```
nnoremap <C-f> :let save_cursor=getcurpos() <bar> %!clang-format -style=file <bar> call setpos('.', save_cursor)<CR>
```

Or make it a function:

```
nnoremap <C-f> :call Clang_format()<CR>

func! Clang_format()
    let save_cursor = getcurpos()
    exe '%!clang-format -style=file'
    call setpos('.', save_cursor)
endfunc
```

Comment: I would rather suggest to use `winsaveview()/winrestview()` as this also prevents changes from the viewport.

Comment: Awesome, that actually works perfectly.